# Recursive method with return

Tags: java, recursion, methods, sum, return

I have to write a recursive method that will count the sum of all even numbers that can not be divided with `7` in an interval form `1` till a parameter.

I cant use any loop. This is how far I came, but it seems that my statement is not correct.

Any suggestions?

```
public static int specialSum (int x){
    return (x % 2 == 0) && (x % 7 != 0) ? specialSum(x - 1) + 1 : 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(specialSum(16));
}
```

Comment: In what way(s) is it "not correct"?

Comment: Are you counting or summing?

Comment: In case with number 16 my result is 31. (It should be something like this: 16 + 12 + 10 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2, he should skip 14 because it can be divided with 7) Why 31? Well I think he gets the first two numbers 16, 15 and after that he stops, so something is not quite okay with my statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find the sum of such (`x % 2 == 0 && x % 7 != 0`) positive (`x > 0`) numbers:

```
public static int specialSum (int x) {
    return x > 0 ?
            specialSum(x - 1) + (x % 2 == 0 && x % 7 != 0 ? x : 0) :
            0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot!
That's the thing I did not get right...so that means I need, and I actually can do more than one Boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recurse to the next number whether or not you count the current one.

```
boolean divisibleBy2Not14 = ((x % 2 == 0) && (x % 7 != 0);
return (divisibleBy2Not14 ? x : 0) + (x > 0 ? specialSum(x - 1) : 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your recursive has two problems:

1. It's trying to return the *count* and not the sum of number that are valid
2. And the recursion does not reach all the branches, because it's terminated as soon as it reaches a non-valid case.

If you want the sum you should return `specialSum(x-1)+x` not `specialSum(x-1)+1`. This is an example that would work:

```
public static int specialSum (int x){
    if(x == 0) return 0; // ← degenerate case
    return ((x % 2 == 0) && (x % 7 != 0) ? specialSum(x - 1) + x : specialSum(x - 1));
}
```

You could add a little clever simplification by replacing `specialSum(x - 1) + x` by `specialSum(x - 2) + x`, because you know that `x - 1` is going to be odd if `x` is even.

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the specialsum method like this:

```
public static int specialSum (int x){
    if(x == 1)  return 0;
    return ((x % 2 == 0) && (x % 7 != 0) ? specialSum(x - 1) + x   : specialSum(x - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to approach it is to first write it out the long way (no ternary operators). Then you can see if it can be shortened:

```
   public static int summer( int n ) {
      if ( n < 2 ) {
         return 0;
      } else if ( (n % 2) == 0 ) {
         if ( (n % 7) == 0 ) {
            return summer( n - 2 ); // n-1 is odd, so skip it
         }
         return n + summer( n - 2 ); // n-1 is odd, so skip it
      } else {
         return summer( n - 1 );
      }
   }
```